# How to extend Eigen's Tensor class?

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor, eigen3, eigenclass

I have created a function to display the shape of a Tensor on eigen.

```
template<typename Scalar_, int rank>
void shape(const Eigen::Tensor<Scalar_, rank>& x)
{
  cout << "( ";  
  for (int i(0); i<x.NumDimensions; i++){
      cout << x.dimensions()[i];
      cout << ",";

  }
  cout << ")";  
}
```

To use it I have to do :

```
Tensor <double,2> t (2,2)
shape(t)
```

I would like to integrate it directly into the tensor class so that we can call it like this:

```
Tensor <double,2> t (2,2)
t.shape
```

How to extend Eigen's Tensor class to add functions?

Comment: why? non-member non-friend function are better choice anyway https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197

Comment: Because I thought it was better to structure the code, if I don't make member functions, I will have a Tensor.h file that contains all the functions to integrate with Tensor. In terms of code structure it's not disturbing ?

Comment: nope, the article is going to the details on way non-member non-friend functions (like your shape one) are better. They increase encapsulation, it is a good reading. If you have a copy of "effective c++" it is expanded.